How to do a for loop in groupplots (pgfplots) to plot pre-calculated regression lines?
I was playing around with groupplots in pgfplots and I could set it up to plot multiple datasets and to discriminate between inliers and outliers by an extra column containing the scpecific labels. The code is here:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    scatter,
    scatter/classes={
            i={mark=*,color=blue}, % Inlier color
            o={mark=*,color=red,thick}  % Outlier color
        },
    group style={
        group size=2 by 2,
        vertical sep=1cm
    }
    ]
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {1,...,4}{
    \edef\tmp{
        \noexpand\nextgroupplot[title=Dataset\i]
        \noexpand\addplot[
        only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic,
        ] table [
        x index=0, % First column is X values
        y=y\i, % Y values are in column i
        meta=label\i % Labels are in the next column
    ] {d1.dat};
    }
    \tmp
    }
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

And the d1.dat contains following datapoints:
x y1 label1 y2 label2 y3 label3 y4 label4
1 2 i 3 i 5 o 4 i
2 3 o 4 i 6 i 7 i
3 5 i 7 i 8 i 10 i

Then, I wanted to try to do something similar by extracting slopes and y interceptions from a file and to plot them using a loop. The file is structured like this:
slope1 intercept1 slope2 intercept2 slope3 intercept3 slope4 intercept4
0.42 -0.63 0.52 -0.33 0.62 -0.83 0.32 -0.23 

What I tried to do was this:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    xlabel={X-axis},
    ylabel={Y-axis},
    group style={
        group size=2 by 2,
        vertical sep=1cm
    }
]
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {1,...,4}{
        \edef\tmp{
            \noexpand\nextgroupplot[title=Dataset \i]
            % Extract slope and intercept for dataset i
            \noexpand\addplot[
                domain=0:10, % Adjust the range as needed
                samples=100, % Number of points to plot the line
                thick,
                red
            ] {(\pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{slope\i}\of{d2.dat}) * x + (\pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{interception\i}\of{d2.dat})};
        }
        \tmp
    }
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

But I don't get it to work.
Just to make it clear, what I want. I want to plot pre-calculated regression lines using a loop in groupplots.

\pgfplotstablegetelem write value into \pgfplotsretval, So you cannot use it directly in the coordinates. Here is a way you could do:
\begin{filecontents*}[force]{d2.dat}
slope1 intercept1 slope2 intercept2 slope3 intercept3 slope4 intercept4
0.42 -0.63 0.52 -0.33 0.62 -0.83 0.32 -0.23 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    xlabel={X-axis},
    ylabel={Y-axis},
    group style={
        group size=2 by 2,
        vertical sep=1.5cm
    }
]
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {1,...,4}{
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{slope\i}\of{d2.dat}
        \xdef\slope{\pgfplotsretval}
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{intercept\i}\of{d2.dat}
        \xdef\intercept{\pgfplotsretval}
        \edef\tmp{
            \noexpand\nextgroupplot[title=Dataset \i]
            % Extract slope and intercept for dataset i
            \noexpand\addplot[
                domain=0:10, % Adjust the range as needed
                samples=100, % Number of points to plot the line
                thick,
                red
            ] {(\noexpand\slope) * x+(\noexpand\intercept)};
        }
        \tmp
    }
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



One thing forget to mention: first row's index is 0 instead 1.
